# How to build and deploy Angular2 with MySQL in godaddy.com

Tags: angular

I currently have a website hosted in godaddy.com that was built on PHP and using MySQL.  I am thinking of converting it to Angular2.  Would you suggest the steps and technologies that I need to use to build and deploy Angular2 to godaddy and how it will communicate to MySQL database?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really broad question, but in sweeping steps.

1. Use your existing MySQL Database
2. Write REST Services using PHP to access MySQL Database
3. Write Angular Code to access those services and create your views
4. Compile your Angular TypeScript code to JavaScript. One such way is to use the [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) project, to create a build.
5. Upload your final build and PHP code to your GoDaddy services.

Step 2 and 3 can be really big steps depending upon the size of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I don't want to use PHP for the services, what would you suggest? Can I use nodejs or other framework that can communicate with mysql and can be deployed to godaddy? I'm not sure about the backend part which is best to use on godaddy.

Comment: If you want to use something other than PHP, there are a ton of options. NodeJS, Java, .NET, ColdFusion, Ruby, or anything that can build rest services. I have no idea about GoDaddy's support of any of those.  If you already have existing PHP code; I'd stick with it.